# ag-grid "isGroupOpenByDefault" property is not working while trying to open the row group by default in Angular ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using row grouping feature to group the rows based on one of the column(like I'm grouping based on client field in my ag-grid table). By-default, I believe its always visible in a closed state. I want to display the row group by-default in open state. For that I'm using `[isGroupOpenByDefault]` property but while using, I'm getting error that
`ERROR in Can't bind to 'isGroupOpenByDefault' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'`.
I'm using Angular ag-grid enterprise and I have added "RowGroupingModule" and "ColumnsToolPanelModule" which has required for the the row grouping and their other properties and `@ag-grid-community/angular` version  is ^25.1.0

Could someone please help me out? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for responding everyone. I found the solution about "isGroupOpenByDefault" not working. I have tested this feature at my localhost where installed version of these two dependencies "@ag-grid-community/angular" and "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model" are 25.1.0. But these "isGroupOpenByDefault" callback have introduced at 25.3.0 version.
I found this point from this Url https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/
Where they have written new feature[Key= AG-5347] in 25.3.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding directly to Grid Options like below,

`isGroupOpenByDefault: (params) => { return (params.field == 'year' && params.key == '2004') || (params.field == 'country' && params.key == 'United States'); };`

Comment: Thank you KAP for responding. I have tried to add in default grid options as well instead of adding @input property in html but still getting same issue. I found the answer about getting issue.